# LINQ join queries on multiple table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have struggling to run linq left on multiple tables.

### tableA

```
Select all the (courseID, code, title) from courseInstances table
```

### tableB

```
select (studyLevel_ID) from Courses table where courseID from tableA = CourseID from tableB. tableB has courseID
```

### tableC

```
Select (StudyLevelDescription) from StudyLevel table where studyLevelID from tableB = studyLevel from tableC.
```

I believe I need left join on table A as I need all the records

I have done separate linq which are working fine but struggling to bring combine result

### CourseInstances results

```
var processedCourseInstance = 
(from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
           join _courses in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID
           into a from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
           orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
           select _courseInstances).ToList();
```

### StudyLevel results for each course

```
 var _CoursesStudyLevel_Lookup = 
  (from _course in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll()
   join _studyLevel in _uof.StudyLevel_Repository.GetAll() on _course.StudyLevelId equals _studyLevel.StudyLevelID
   select new {_course.CourseID, _course.StudyLevelId, _studyLevel.LevelDescription  }).ToList();
```

I have managed to combine two results but NOT with LEFT join on CourseInstance table. This time I used LINQPad

```
from _courseInstances in CourseInstances
join _courses in Courses on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID
join _studylevel in StudyLevels on _courses.StudyLevelId equals _studylevel.StudyLevelID
orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
select new {_courseInstances.CourseID, _courseInstances.CourseCode, _courseInstances.CourseTitle, _courseInstances.UCASCode, _courses.StudyLevelId, _studylevel.LevelDescription, _studylevel.SLevelType }
```

for above SQL version as following;

```
SELECT [t0].[CourseID], [t0].[CourseCode], [t0].[CourseTitle], 

[t0].[UCASCode], [t1].[StudyLevelId], [t2].[LevelDescription], [t2].[SLevelType]
    FROM [CourseInstances] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [Courses] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CourseID] = ([t1].[CourseID])
    INNER JOIN [StudyLevel] AS [t2] ON [t1].[StudyLevelId] = ([t2].[StudyLevelID])
ORDER BY [t0].[CourseCode]
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: A left join in LINQ can be made with the `into` keyword and `.DefaultIfEmpty()`. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: My question is right on tableC heading "I have done separate linq which are working fine but struggling to bring combine result" and then at the end while I am also trying to sort it, I have mention that I want to use left join in linq, where I managed to do upto inner join

Comment: seriously why I been negative marked for that ...

Comment: Do you have the original SQL query?

Comment: I just update my question at the end with sql but it is with inner join

Comment: And you want a left join in linq? On what table (courses or studylevel)?

Comment: on courseInstance table. so I want all the courses from courseInstance table

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want something like this?

```
from _courseInstances in CourseInstances
join c in Courses on _courseInstances.CourseID equals c.CourseID into courses
from _courses in courses.DefaultIfEmpty()
join sl in StudyLevels on _courses.StudyLevelId equals sl.StudyLevelID into studyLevels
from _studylevel in studyLevels.DefaultIfEmtpy()
orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
select new {
       _courseInstances.CourseID, 
       _courseInstances.CourseCode, 
       _courseInstances.CourseTitle,
       _courseInstances.UCASCode, 
       _courses.StudyLevelId, 
       _studylevel.LevelDescription, 
       _studylevel.SLevelType 
    }
}
```

You can create a `LINQ` left join query with the *into* keyword and *.DefaultIfEmpt()*.

Comment: You need to check if `_studylevel` is null before projecting it like `_studylevel.LevelDescription` because it may throw NRE.